# SonarLint in VS2017 reports different issues to connected SonarCloud analysis

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have a new project on SonarCloud which is analyzing a fairly new C# solution which contains a tiny amount of code at present. I have installed the latest version of SonarLint and successfully connected the project to the SonarCloud project I have set up. The SonarCloud tasks are part of the VSTS build definition and the analysis is running on build with results being reported to SonarCloud.

Some issues - such as "S2933 - Fields that are only assigned in the constructor should be readonly" are reported in SonarCloud and reported in the VS IDE warnings window when code analysis is run locally. This is what I was expecting.

Other issues, such as "S1451 - Add or update the header of this file" are only reported in the IDE.

Some other issues, such as "common-cs:InsufficientCommentDensity" are only reported on SonarCloud, and not in the IDE.

I would like the IDE and SonarCloud to report the same issues as each other; my understanding is that that is the whole point of SonarLint connected mode.

I have created a custom Quality Profile on SonarCloud that inherits from "C# - Sonar way" and activated every rule, which now total 330, although bizarrely when I view anything beyond the first 100 rules on the website I am always presented with the "Activate" button nomatter how many times I click it and refresh the page.

If I look at the ruleset file that SonarQube has added to the project in VS, it contains the 330 rules that are in the server quality profile and has ticks next to all of them. There are a further 10 or so rules in this ruleset file that are deactivated and do not appear at all on SonarCloud.

What do I have to do to make the IDE and VSTS analyses consistent?

Answer (score 1):

Some rules act a bit weird indeed.

- `S1451` has parameter (the expected file header) and is thus disabled unless you manually configure it. Even in connected mode SonarLint for Visual Studio does not support synchronization of parameters. [This feature](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/issues/176) is in our backlog and most probably we will be working on it soon.
- `common-cs:*` is a server-side rule (e.g. it runs on SonarQube/SonarCloud) and cannot be executed in SonarLint for Visual Studio.

You could configure the `S1451` and the other parametrized rules by adding a new XML file with content similar to [this file (link)](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/blob/master/src/SonarLint.xml), then reference the file in your project like [we do (link)](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-visualstudio/blob/master/src/Integration.Vsix/Integration.Vsix.csproj#L466-L468).

I was unable to reproduce the QualityProfile Active/Inactive status problem, it would be helpful to share what browser/version are you using and perhaps a short screen capture video of the behavior would be a nice way to demonstrate the problem.

Update: Apparently one of our SonarQube devs managed to reproduce the problem with the QP rule activation/deactivation and created a ticket:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10685

Comment: Thank you for explaining. S1451 though is running in the IDE only and not on the server side. I haven't got the facility to make a video but it's Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit).